# Is browse and upload function work in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload

I have an application in which i have a button **browse**, which onclick should open all files, folders existing in my android mobile. I got a doubt like is this possible to browse  and choose the files to upload? I observed that `<input type="file">` is not working in android due to security reasons. Can anyone please show me some good working examples on how to browse files from mobile to upload?

Comment: Since I haven't worked with PhoneGap before, then I hope this [Java Android project](http://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/) could give you some points…

Comment: @SheIs_LeThiCongNhan Thanks i'll go through the link you specified.

Comment: You're welcome  :-)  Unfortunately I can't help on PhoneGap. About your goal, as far as I know, you don't need any permission.

Comment: I've found a file chooser for PhoneGap [here](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/file-chooser-dialog-for-phonegap-application/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete Code::

**AndroidExplorer.class**

```
public class AndroidExplorer extends ListActivity {

private List<String> item = null;
private List<String> path = null;
private String root="/";
private TextView myPath;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);
    getDir(root);
}

private void getDir(String dirPath)
{
    myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);

    item = new ArrayList<String>();
    path = new ArrayList<String>();

    File f = new File(dirPath);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if(!dirPath.equals("/"))
    {

        item.add(root);
        path.add(root);

        item.add("../");
        path.add(f.getParent());

    }

    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if(file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
    setListAdapter(fileList);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    File file = new File(path.get(position));

    if (file.isDirectory())
    {
        if(file.canRead())
            getDir(path.get(position));
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    }).show();
    }
}
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/path"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
<TextView
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="No Data"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response i'll go through the code you attached. But i'm working on phonegap so do you have any samples how to browse files using phonegap?

Comment: Sorry bro..I havnt worked on phonegap!